# LINQPAD trying to specify SQL Server Compact 4 databases

Tags: database, linqpad

I have 2 SQL Server Compact 4 databases (sdf files) that I'm trying to query using LINQPAD v4.28.2 (with autocompletion option). I opened the 2 sdf files in LINQPAD but when I try to specify the database to use (e.g. database1.table1.Take(50)) I get an error that says "The name 'database1' does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 0):

LINQPad 4.28 premium supports cross-database querying - but only for SQL Server, not SQL CE. I'm almost certain SQL CE itself forbids cross-database querying - have you tried it in SSMS or VS?

Comment: As far as I know SSCE 4 is not supported in SSMS or VS.